# MS-Word header is different on some pages with a short chapter title

Tags: ms-word

I created a Word document with a header. Inside the header I implemented a `StyleRef` to receive the chapter title from a table of content and the pagination. Both are separated with two tabs.

Image with a correct header - chapter title on the left & pagination on the right:

[image: 1]

A header with a longer title works also like intended.

But if I add more chapters with a shorter title, the header creates a paragraph between the chapter title and the pagination:

[image: 3]

So from my state of knowledge every header should be the same, unless I set a different section.

- Does someone have a solution to remove automatically the paragraph like in image 3?
- Can someone explain me, why this error occurs?

Comment: Display the ruler, open the header, check where the tab stops are and [what type of text alignment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-clear-or-remove-tab-stops-06969e0f-2c81-4fe0-8df5-88f18087a8e0) they have.

Comment: Thanks that completely solved my problem.